# Date Format in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, date

How can I display today's date in format like Monday December, 29th 2014 modifying this

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!today()}" /> </apex:outputText>
```

this will display like 29/12/2014

Thank you

Comment: Means you have to display date like in this format 29/12/2014 ?

Comment: My code didnt show up, I edit it. No, but this one Monday December, 29th 2014

Comment: Date formatting is always a bit tough in Visualforce - a gentle reminder from the platform that the output is supposed to be an artefact of the running user's locale and language. I might have burned my fingers a few times! :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE MMMM',' d y}"> <apex:param value="{!today()}" /> </apex:outputText>
```

That will display something like: Monday December, 29 2014

The date formatting is based on [simple date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Note that to add "st","th","nd","rd" to the days additional coding is required, you may need an apex solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE' 'MMMM', 'd' 'yyyy}"> 
    <apex:param value="{!today()}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

It produces the following when I test in my dev org

[image]

Take a look at Java Simple Date Format for additional details and other possibilities

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Why it shows 2015???

Comment: Great point.  Didn't notice.  Just updated.  Changed the year from `YYYY` to `yyyy`.  Now showing 2014 as it should.

Comment: what is the difference with my answer? an image that displayed the wrong date at first?

Comment: The answers are no different.  You must have answered while I was still typing my answer.